# Which objects can be accessed with DotNetFactory?

Tags: qtp

I wonder to know which objects can I access using QTP DotNetFactory object. Is there any list and their API of accessible objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access any .NET object using `DotNetFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetFactory objects and supported methods are available in qtp help.

If not then in qtp editor,qtp's intellisense would help you in getting method of a specific .net object